# Clear particular notifications

Tags: android, push-notification, android-notifications

For example i have five categories, A,B,C,D,E

Received 2 Push notifications for Category A

Received 3 Push notifications for Category B

Received 4 Push notifications for Category C

Again Received 2 Push notifications for Category A

So total 11 notifications are received

if i clicked on any one of Category A notification then All Category A notifications to be removed. The remaining B and C notifications(7 notification) should be available in notification section

Any one know how to do this, Any example is available to handle this scenario?

Is this possible in Android?

Answer (score 0):

If you get push notifications without a `data` section, then you are out of luck as far as i can tell, because those are managed by the system. Your app does not get informed when it arrives (and therefore you can't keep track of how many are displayed), only when one is clicked.

You need notifications where your app gets started through the `onMessageReceived` callback of your `FirebaseMessagingService` implementation. To make this happen, your notifications need to have a `data` payload.

In this callback you raise your local notification for yourself, thus providing a `NotificationChannel` and a unique id for each notification.

Then you are in full control, which notifications to cancel, and which to keep alive.
Your service should keep track of which notifications are shown, in a simple list, containing all ids by channel (= category).

Maybe these snippets can help you:

#### For Android 8 and later

Please read the extensive doc's for the new `NotificationChannels` at [developer.android.com](https://developer.android.com/training/notify-user/channels)

#### For older versions

Simply keep a list of all shown notifications in your service implementation and cancel out all those you want to close.

```
NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager)
    context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
if (notificationManager != null)
    notificationManager.cancel(id);
```